# Will thread in thread pool (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) be used for other tasks when in sleep?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

I have a thread pool created from ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:

```
threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
```

this ThreadPoolTaskExecutor will execute runnables, each runnable has a `Thread.sleep(6000);` call during the task execution.

So when I execute the 1st task and when the 1st task calls `Thread.sleep(6000)` to sleep, at that time, execute the 2nd task, will it be possible the 2nd task will use the thread of the 1st task or interrupt the thread used by the 1st task? since it is in sleep.

Comment: IMO people get too hung up about how `sleep` works. From the _application's_ perspective, it's dirt simple:`sleep(6000)` does _nothing._ It does nothing for six seconds, and then it returns. From the OS scheduler's perspective, that means that the thread won't be needing the CPU core for the next six seconds, but that's transparent to the application. No matter what the OS actually does to make the thread "sleep," it will always maintain the _illusion_ that the `sleep` call did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not automatically. If a normal Java Thread is sleeping, then it's sleeping.

Also, Threads are really cheap nowadays, I would not bother with details like that.

Working around the sleep and let that 'sleeping' Thread do some other work is really really hard to manage properly and easily will lead to loads and loads of unforeseen problems.

In your situation, what you COULD improve is that the pool size is not fixed but dynamic, releasing (destroying) threads when they haven't been used for some time (say: a minute).
If more threads are needed, the pool will create new Threads, up to the given limit. (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`)
That's especially helpful on a server, because 99% of threads on there are just idle (not even 'actively' sleeping).

Here are some details that might interest you: https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

Especially check out ForkJoinPool: https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join, because this comes very close to a very similar problem.

Comment: Whether a Java thread is "cheap" or not is very relative and depending on your use case, it could be "expensive". Why would brilliant people spend countless hours on producing asynchronous IO frameworks and libraries, if limiting thread usage doesn't improve latency and throughput? And why do we have the Java Loom project "looming"  around the corner?

Comment: @forty-two, "Why would brilliant people spend countless hours...?" Same reason somebody would implement a `Complex` number class even though everything to do with complex numbers can be defined in terms of reals. When you create a new Java function, new package, new library, etc.; you are, in a real sense, extending the language. You provide programmers with a more concise means of expressing the solutions to certain problems. "Async" is a different way of describing, _and thinking about,_ concurrency. Some people find it a better fit than threads to their problems.

Comment: @forty-two I know that lots and lots of people say that *asynchronous IO* is faster than simply using loads and loads of threads. But I rather see that as a consequence of a) resource prioritization and b) the use of monitors/locks that rely on hardware and OS levels, rather than an in-software implementation. All the tests I know so far are C/C++, Python, JavaScript implementations where the statistics support that claim. So do you know / could you please link me any statistics to that topic, based on apps programmed in Java?